# Logical Error-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am not getting the correct output.

```
data.m
---------

@implementation data

- (id) initWithID:(int) uMessageId withData:(id)pData withSize:(size_t) uDataSize
{
        //if(self=[super init])
        //{
           // Initialize the member variables
            m_uSessionId    = 0x00;
            m_chSequenceChar= 0;

           // Initialize values from derived class
            m_nMessageId    = uMessageId;
            m_pData         = (int*)pData;              
            m_uDataSize     = (int)uDataSize;            
        //}
        return self;    
}

- (BOOL) TxCreateImage:(id) pData withLen:(id)uLen
{
    sprintf((char *)pData,"%x%d%d%d",ASCII_STX,m_uSessionId,m_chSequenceChar,m_nMessageId);
    //uLen = ENCODED_MSG_DATA_OFFSET;
    NSLog(@"%s",pData);
    return YES;
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

data_derived.m  //derived class of data
--------------------
@implementation requestSession

- (id)init
{
    char* pData[4096];
    size_t asize = sizeof(st);
    self=[super initWithID:ID withData:(id)pData withSize:asize];
    if (self) {
        data* dat = [[data alloc]init]; 
        [dat TxCreateImage:self withLen:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

test2.m
---------
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    requestSession* session = [[requestSession alloc]init];


    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}

remote.h
-----------

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

struct RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG  //Message Data
{
    int  uDeviceID;
    int  uProtocolVersion;
    int  uReserved[5];
};

typedef enum
{
    RM_REQUEST_SESSION = 0x11    //Message ID

} REMOTE_MESSAGE_ID;

@interface remote : NSObject {

}

@end

data.h
---------

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "remote.h"

@interface data : NSObject {

    @public

        int m_nMessageId;      //Message ID
        int m_uSessionId;      //Session ID
        int m_chSequenceChar;  //Sequence ID

        int* m_pData;          //Integer buffer to carry data
        int m_uDataSize;       //Datasize

}

- (id)initWithID:(int) uMessageId withData:(id)pData withSize:(size_t) uDataSize;
- (void)dealloc;
- (BOOL) TxCreateImage:(id) pData withLen:(id)uLen;
//+ (id)CreateMessage:(REMOTE_MESSAGE_ID)nMessageNumber;
//+ (id)CreateMessage:(const int*)szMessageName;

@end

data_derived.h
---------------------

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "data.h"

#define DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(ClassID)\
enum                                 \
{                                    \
    ID = ClassID                     \
};                                   \

@interface requestSession : data {

 @public
    DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(RM_REQUEST_SESSION);
    struct RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG st;
    int size;

}

-(id)init;
-(void)dealloc;

@end
```

The expected output is

> 2 0 0 17

. But its printing me

> 2 0 0 0

.

I need to pass the values assigned in

> initWithData method

in data.m to

> TxCreateMessage

in data.m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer was irrelevant since I missed something in your question. the problem is that you are casting a `int *` to `char *`, pointer casting is the root to many many issues (in this case, it's probably an endianess problem.)

If you want to use sprintf, use it on `char*`, not `int*`:

```
- (BOOL) TxCreateImage:(id) pData withLen:(id)uLen
{
    char printStr[30];
    sprintf(printStr,"%x%d%d%d",ASCII_STX,m_uSessionId,m_chSequenceChar,m_nMessageId);
    //uLen = ENCODED_MSG_DATA_OFFSET;
    NSLog(@"%s",printStr);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I could not get the values changed by initWithData onto TxCreateMessage as its in Local scope.

Comment: m_nMessageId is 17 but it will not print it.It will print as 0.The variables assigned are local to that scope in initWithID. So the values are not printed in the other function TxCreateMessage.Why is the need for char printStr[30] in the code above.